# How to delete invisible characters using Notepad++

Tags: unicode, notepad++

this question may have similar siblings, but all answers are pretty cryptic and are unfollowable. I am asking here for specific baby-steps, for dummies instructions.

Overleaf is complaining about some (U+2009) characters in my *.bib file. I want them removed.
I was able to do it a year ago on notepad++ via "find and replace" and cannot figure it out again. It was very simple and not cryptic.

I simply want to be able to find these characters. I know that notepad++ can do it. I need a holding hand here.
I've tried \x{u2009}, \x{2009}, \x{u+2009}... nothing works

Answer (score 0):

The steps:

1. Open the file in Notepad++
2. Ctrl+h
3. Write `\u2009` in "Find what:"
4. Nothing in "Replace with:"
5. Make sure "Match whole word only" is NOT checked
6. Select "Extended" search mode
7. Click "Replace All"

Comment: self answers are welcome, but this is off-topic here and should be on [su]

Comment: thank you @phuclv. How do I move it there neatly? I am not familiar

Comment: @phuclv: Notepad++ questions are valid on SO.

Comment: @Toto only when it's [in the scope](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development*. Replacing text isn't unique to programming in any way